# Google maps api keys: dev -> staging -> production workflow

Tags: google-maps, api-key

Does anyone have a good solution for managing the maps api key, given that:

- developers work locally, using localhost
- we have a staging server, accessed internally via http://stagehost and externally (for customers) via IP address
- finally, a production server (http://some.domain.com)

Two questions:

First, how do people manage their keys in this type of scenario, given that there's always a chance for a mixup.  Internal servers are not accessible via stagehost.domain.com

Second, how can we address the staging server issue?  The ip address is not accessible internally.  Is this possible?

Comment: Probably not really helpful in your case, but from v3 (currently a Labs/beta) of the Google Maps API no API keys are required anymore: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/#Welcome

Comment: @tomlog where under that link does it say that you don't need a key?

Comment: @Simon: it looks like the page has changed. It now is mentioned on the following page: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/basics.html

Answer (score 1):

I have a table in my database that stores the Google Map keys for all of my different URLs.  Then I just pull out the correct key based on the URL.  This lets the same code work for dev, test, & production across 100 sites.